# ImportError: cannot import name _fblas on Mac

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scikit-image

I am semi-new to python and I am trying to use scikit-image, but as soon as I try to import, I get errors. I have gotten past a few of them, but I am stuck on this one when I try to import:

```
    In [8]: from skimage import data, io, filter
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-7863d911e191> in <module>()
----> 1 from skimage import data, io, filter

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/data/__init__.py in <module>()
     10 
     11 from .. import data_dir
---> 12 from ..io import imread, use_plugin
     13 
     14 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/__init__.py in <module>()
      9 from .collection import *
     10 
---> 11 from ._io import *
     12 from ._image_stack import *
     13 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/_io.py in <module>()
      6 
      7 from ..io.manage_plugins import call_plugin
----> 8 from ..color import rgb2grey
      9 from .util import file_or_url_context
     10 from ..exposure import is_low_contrast

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/color/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .colorconv import (convert_colorspace,
      2                         guess_spatial_dimensions,
      3                         rgb2hsv,
      4                         hsv2rgb,
      5                         rgb2xyz,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/color/colorconv.py in <module>()
     56 from warnings import warn
     57 import numpy as np
---> 58 from scipy import linalg
     59 from ..util import dtype
     60 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py in <module>()
    170 from .linalg_version import linalg_version as __version__
    171 
--> 172 from .misc import *
    173 from .basic import *
    174 from .decomp import *

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 from numpy.linalg import LinAlgError
----> 5 from .blas import get_blas_funcs
      6 from .lapack import get_lapack_funcs
      7 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/blas.py in <module>()
    153 import numpy as _np
    154 
--> 155 from scipy.linalg import _fblas
    156 try:
    157     from scipy.linalg import _cblas

ImportError: cannot import name _fblas
```

I have searched for this issue, but while others had success with simply uninstalling and reinstalling python, I have not. Also, others had Windows specific solutions, but I am on a Mac. I'm fairly confident I'm using the newest versions of python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, and skikit-image, since I only installed them all last week.

Comment: It looks like your scipy is not correctly installed.  What did you use to install it?  If you are running pip, you can do ``pip install scipy --force-reinstall``.  Otherwise, perhaps try the Anaconda distribution.

Comment: I thought I had used pip the first time, but maybe not. This worked perfectly; Thanks!

Comment: Am I the only one who hates the idea of specialized distributions on Windows like Anaconda just because the Python On Windows world can't get its packaging ducks in a row?  Wheels are out there, and pip install scipy should JUST WORK on all versions of windows. It's 2016 now, and this is still a mess.

Comment: @WarrenP Watch this space.  Things are almost resolved.