# statsmodels v0.6.1 won't import: _fblas issue

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statsmodels

I had been using statsmodels from an older anaconda distribution and now it's failing to import after updating to anaconda 2.4.0.

```
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cnelson/PythonUtils/statsmodels-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-0.5-x86_64.egg/statsmodels/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,
  File "/Users/cnelson/PythonUtils/statsmodels-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/statsmodels/tools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "/Users/cnelson/PythonUtils/statsmodels-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/statsmodels/tools/tools.py", line 8, in <module>
   from scipy.linalg import svdvals
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import blas
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/blas.py", line 145, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: cannot import name _fblas
```

I also sometimes get this related error if I try importing:

```
   from scipy.linalg import _fblas
   ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I've tried replacing the current default statsmodels 0.6.1 package files with old statsmodels 0.5.0 package files, and the same error is still coming up. Next I'll try copying over an old version of scipy/linalg. I'm on a MacOSX machine. Somehow the various numpy/scipy/statsmodels packages aren't compatible. Any workarounds appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `conda update scipy` ?

Comment: Yeah, it just says "All requested packages already installed." Ditto for numpy.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661592/importerror-cannot-import-name-fblas-on-mac

Comment: There was a conflict with other versions of the site-packages installed in other directories. Clean install of anacondas fixed the problem and statsmodels is behaving again.